# Variable insertion breaks command

Tags: bash, macos, fastlane

I want to put this in a script:

```
fastlane sigh resign test.ipa --signing_identity "iPhone Distribution: test KGaA" --provisioning_profile Dist_InHouse_test_All_Wildcard.mobileprovision
```

How I put it into my script:

```
ipaPath=$1
signingIdentity="--signing_identity \"iPhone Distribution: test KGaA\""
provisioningProfileFile="Dist_InHouse_test_All_Wildcard.mobileprovision"

fastlane sigh resign ${ipaPath} ${signingIdentity} ${provisioningProfile}
```

This breaks the command. Apparently the `${signingIdentity}` variable consists only of `--signing_identity`.

```
[22:07:22]: Couldn't find signing identity ''.
```

---

I've tried double quotes:

```
fastlane sigh resign ${ipaPath} "${signingIdentity}" ${provisioningProfile}
```

but that yields:

```
invalid option: --signing_identity "iPhone Distribution: test KGaA"
```

Obviously that is a valid option.

---

I've tried single quotes:

```
fastlane sigh resign ${ipaPath} '${signingIdentity}' ${provisioningProfile}
```

but that yields that I do not have the `--signing_identity` option at all.

---

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/questions/360966/how-do-i-use-a-bash-variable-string-containing-quotes-in-a-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use *[arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays):*

```
ipaPath=$1
signingIdentity=( --signing_identity "iPhone Distribution: test KGaA" )
provisioningProfileFile=( --provisioning_profile "Dist_InHouse_test_All_Wildcard.mobileprovision" )

fastlane sigh resign "${ipaPath}" "${signingIdentity[@]}" "${provisioningProfile[@]}"
```